# How should i calculate the throughput

Tags: performance, benchmarking

I have a log that is formatted like this:

```
<timestamp>,<response time>
<timestamp>,<response time>
<timestamp>,<response time>
```

I can see two ways of calculating the throughput here:

1. For each response time calculate the would be throughput as if all requests would have this response time (# of clients and thinktime is known)
2. Average the number of responses for each 1s window in the log

Is there any other way and which should i choose?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.


Comment: If you are going to connect this to anything else I would pick the 2nd because otherwise you will likely see big jumps in your throughput(if a message is lost or something like this the response time can suddenly be much larger causes throughput to drop to near zero for a single response).

Answer (score 0):

To calculate average throughput for the entire data-set, you could count the number of requests over the entire time period.  So, the number of rows divided by max timestamp minus min timestamp in seconds should give you requests per second.